# How to enable line numbering in SynEdit?

Tags: delphi, synedit

I have recently downloaded SynEdit and I'm wondering how to enable line numbering (like in Lazarus)?
I don't found anything at the internet.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIRC it's some sub-property of `Gutter`.

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt - thanks, I'll read something about it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on [`code found here`](http://nsisedit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r17/branches/ODScriptEdit/Source/UConfig.pas) try to use the:

```
SynEdit1.Gutter.ShowLineNumbers := True;
```

Comment: +1 and also be sure which the gutter is visible,  `SynEdit1.Gutter.Visible := True;`

Comment: Is there a docu for all available options?

Comment: @Hidden, I'm afraid  there isn't (I couldn't find any).